flutter url_launcher throw PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
I'm getting this error while use url_launcher on my project:
PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null), stack: #0      UrlLauncherApi.canLaunchUrl
messages.g.dart:88
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      UrlLauncherAndroid.canLaunch
url_launcher_android.dart:31
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      canLaunch
url_launcher.dart:131
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      EmailUtils.sendEmail
email_util.dart:24
<asynchronous suspension>

Here it's my environment
Engine • revision 3.7.3.2
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.0
and then I put the reference into pubspec.yaml:
url_launcher: ^6.0.20

and then write a function to launch Email:
  Future<void> sendEmail(String emailAddress,
      {String subject = '', String body = ''}) async {
    final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: emailAddress,
      query: encodeQueryParameters(
          <String, String>{'subject': subject, 'body': body}),
    );
    log('$emailLaunchUri');
    if (await canLaunch(emailLaunchUri.toString())) {
      await launch(emailLaunchUri.toString());
    } else {
      log('unable to start email);
    }
  }


but when I hotreload to my device and trying to use the func, it throws PlatformException in UrlLauncherApi, tells me it's unable to establish connection on channel.
/// Returns true if the URL can definitely be launched.
  Future<bool> canLaunchUrl(String arg_url) async {
    final BasicMessageChannel<Object?> channel = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
        'dev.flutter.pigeon.url_launcher_android.UrlLauncherApi.canLaunchUrl',
        codec,
        binaryMessenger: _binaryMessenger);
    final List<Object?>? replyList =
        await channel.send(<Object?>[arg_url]) as List<Object?>?;
    if (replyList == null) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'channel-error',
        message: 'Unable to establish connection on channel.',
      );
    } else if (replyList.length > 1) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: replyList[0]! as String,
        message: replyList[1] as String?,
        details: replyList[2],
      );
    } else if (replyList[0] == null) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'null-error',
        message: 'Host platform returned null value for non-null return value.',
      );
    } else {
      return (replyList[0] as bool?)!;
    }
  }

Did anyone else meet this problem?
